In Shopify, how do I refresh the cart after applying discount code?
I could use some help. We're using Dawn theme. My goal is to auto-apply a discount code to cart to cart for only certain customers which I will eventually control with a tag or metafield. I can successfully auto-apply the discount code, but I can't figure out how to refresh the cart contents showing the product discount without reloading the whole page. Here's the code:
const discountCode = 'PSR';
fetch(`/discount/${discountCode}`)
  .then(() => {
    // After the discount code has been applied, force the cart to update
    // so the discount is visible
    return fetch('/cart/update.js', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ updates: { [discountCode]: 1 } }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
  })
  .then(() => {
    // Refresh cart contents to show discount
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cart:build', { bubbles: true }));
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('cart:refresh', { bubbles: true, detail: cartData }));
  });

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated!
